# how to make combination of product variants in php via user input

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm creating multiple product variant's where user creates options for the product and and add values to options. after that when adding a product user select options for the product such as color, size or or for mobile ram, color, storage with fixed options quantity and price. I have created the database for it but i am unable to bind the variants related to product as per user input. As i m doing this in simplest form of php without oop concept but i am unable to do this

i have already tried using array. but unable to bind the options like :-

```
options

option_id option_name
1        Size
2        Color
3        Ram
4        Inch
5        Storage

option_values

value_id option_id    value_name

1          1            S
2          1            M
3          1            L
4          2            Red
5          2            Black
6          3            4GB
7          3            8GB
8          5            500GB

products_variants

product_id    option_id    value_id    sku_var
1               1             2           SKU_a1
1               1             2           SKU_a2
1               2             4           SKU_a1
1               2             5           SKU_a2


sku_variant_vlaues

quantity    price   sku_var
 5          100     SKU_a1
 8          120     SKU_a2
```

// Posting data using php

// FIXED Options

```
$product_quantity = isset($_POST['product_quantity ']) ? $_POST['product_quantity '] : '0';

$product_price = isset($_POST['product_price']) ? $_POST['product_price'] : '0';
```

/*---------------------- OTHER VARIANT -------------------*/

// this variable is ($all_options_filled) where user chooses which option to be added in product variant like color, size, ram, storage, inch, width etc.
in this variable all the input field name are stored as field1, field2, field3

```
foreach($all_options_filled as $aof_field_name){

if(!empty(trim($aof_field_name))){

$other_options = $con->query("SELECT `option_id`, `option_key`, `option_name` FROM `options` WHERE `option_key`='".$aof_field_name."' AND `status`='ACTIVE' ORDER BY `position` ASC LIMIT 1");

if($other_options->num_rows>0){ 

$row_other_options=mysqli_fetch_array($other_options);                                  
$roo_option_id= $row_other_options['option_id'];
$roo_option_key = $row_other_options['option_key'];
$roo_option_name = $row_other_options['option_name'];

$multiple_option_name[] = isset($_POST[$roo_option_key]) ? $_POST[$roo_option_key] : ''; // array + multiple fields ## multiple array

$multiple_option_id[] = $roo_option_id; // all posted fields id's

}
}
}
```

/*---------------------- OTHER VARIANT -------------------*/

after inserting product data ->
getting the latest id of product as a ( $product_latest_id )
and sku id and sku title as per product as a ( $sku_latest_id , $sku_title )

### below i am inserting the variants

```
if(!empty($multiple_option_name)){ // this variable came from other variants - those are created by user

//foreach($multiple_option_name as $one_multiple_option){
//var_dump($multiple_option_name);

for($i=0; $i<=sizeof($multiple_option_name)-1; $i++){
    $multiple_option_name_1 = $multiple_option_name[$i];
    $single_option_id = $multiple_option_id[$i];
    if(!empty($multiple_option_name_1)){

            //var_dump($one_multiple_option); echo "<br>";

            if(!empty($multiple_option_name_1)){

                //foreach($multiple_option_name_1 as $one_option_value){
                //var_dump($one_option_value); echo "=> $single_option_id <br>";

                for($j=0; $j<=sizeof($multiple_option_name_1)-1; $j++){

                    $one_option_value = $multiple_option_name_1[$j];

                    if(!empty($one_option_value)){

                        $get_one_option_value_id = $con->query("SELECT `value_id` FROM `option_values` WHERE `option_id`='".$single_option_id."' AND `value_name`='".$one_option_value."'");
                        if($get_one_option_value_id->num_rows>0){
                            list($g_option_value_id)=mysqli_fetch_array($get_one_option_value_id);
                        }else{

                            $goov_get_page_number=mysqli_query($con,"SELECT max(`position`) as position FROM `option_values` WHERE `option_id`='".$single_option_id."' ORDER BY `value_id` DESC LIMIT 1");
                            if($goov_get_page_number->num_rows==1){
                                $goov_row_pos = mysqli_fetch_array($goov_get_page_number);
                                $goov_position = $goov_row_pos['position']+1;

                            }else{
                                $goov_position = 1;
                            }

                            $create_one_option_value_id = $con->query("INSERT INTO `option_values`(`option_id`, `value_name`, `position`, `status`) VALUES
                            ('".$single_option_id."', '".$one_option_value."', '".$goov_position."', 'ACTIVE')");

                            $get_latest_one_option_value_id = $con->query("SELECT `value_id` FROM `option_values` 
                            WHERE `option_id`='".$single_option_id."'  AND `value_name`='".$one_option_value."' AND `position`='".$goov_position."' AND `status`='ACTIVE'");
                            list($g_option_value_id)=mysqli_fetch_array($get_latest_one_option_value_id);

                        }

                        $sku_var = $sku_title."-$product_latest_id-$single_option_id-$g_option_value_id";

                        $insert_product_variant_values = $con->query("INSERT INTO `product_variant_values`(`product_id`, `option_id`, `value_id`, `value`, `sku_var`) VALUES
                        ('".$product_latest_id."', '".$single_option_id."', '".$g_option_value_id."', '".$one_option_value."', '".$sku_var."')");



                            $p_quantity = $product_quantity[$j];
                            if($p_quantity>0){
                                $is_quantity_stock = 1;
                            }else{
                                $is_quantity_stock = 0;
                            }

                            $p_show_price = $show_price[$j];

                            $p_variant_currency = $admin_currency_code; // product currency
                            $p_price = $product_price[$j];

                            $p_variant_status = "ACTIVE";

                            $insert_sku_variant_vlaues = $con->query("INSERT INTO `sku_variant_vlaues`(`sku_id`, `product_id`, `sku_var`, 
                            `stock`, `is_stock`, `show_price`, `currency`, `price`, `status`) VALUES ('".$sku_latest_id."', '".$product_latest_id."', '".$sku_var."',
                            '".$p_quantity."', '".$is_quantity_stock."', '".$p_show_price."', '".$p_variant_currency."', '".$p_price."', '".$p_variant_status."') ");



                    }

                }
            }   
    }
}                                       
}
```

below is the table structure used for database:

```
product table -
product_id
product_name


Sku table-
sku_id
sku_title
product_id


options table -
option_id
option_key // used as input field name in front id
option_name

option values table-
value_id
option_id
value_name

product_variant_values table -
product_variant_value_id
product_id
option_id
value_id
sku_var -> // i am using this by adding (sku title, product_id, option_id and value_id) to match it unique to (sku_variant_vlaues table) so i can identify which option is used for which quantity and price

sku_variant_vlaues table -
id - primary key
sku_id
product_id
sku_var -> same sku value from (product_variant_values) table
quantity
price
```

Answer (score 0):

`$postData = array();`

`// $option_id you need to pass option value i create array so i print key you need to print object which contain the id of the option'`

`$option_array = [1 => 'Size' , 2=> 'Color'];`

```
foreach ($option_array as $option_id => $value) { ?>
     <input type="checkbox" name="option_type_id[<?php echo $option_id?>]" value="1">
<?php
}  


$i = 0;
foreach ($option_array as $key => $option_type) {

   $postData['option_type_id'][$key] = array();
   $i++;
   $array = $option_values[$key];

   foreach ($array as $option_value_id => $value) { 
       $postData['option_type_id'][$key][] = $option_value_id;
    ?>
     <input type="checkbox" name="option_type_id[<?php echo $key?>][option_values][]" value="<?php echo $option_value_id?>">
   <?php }
   }

   $variants_data = array();

   $lastInsertedProductId = 1;
   $lastInsertedProductSKU = "SKU1";
   foreach ($postData['option_type_id'] as $key => $value) {


    foreach ($value as $option_id => $option_value) {

      $variants_data[] = array(
        'product_id' => $lastInsertedProductId, 
        'sku_var' => $lastInsertedProductSKU, 
        'option_id' => $key,
        'option_value' => $option_value,
       );
    }
    }
```

// it produce out put like this

```
    Array
    (
      [0] => Array
      (
        [product_id] => 1
        [sku_var] => SKU1
        [option_id] => 1
        [option_value] => 1
       )

[1] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 1
        [sku_var] => SKU1
        [option_id] => 1
        [option_value] => 2
    )

[2] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 1
        [sku_var] => SKU1
        [option_id] => 2
        [option_value] => 4
    )

[3] => Array
    (
        [product_id] => 1
        [sku_var] => SKU1
        [option_id] => 2
        [option_value] => 6
    )
```

)

`echo "<pre>";print_r($variants_data);die;`
//So now you can simple check the output is matched according your database 
 when you post this inputs your functionality will work like this hope this will solve your problem